# Finding Greatest value on array of indexes

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have to find the greatest value of array and return its index position.

This is my snippets of code:

```
function findGreaterNumbers(array) {
    for(var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if(array[i].length !== 0) {
            var result = Math.max.apply(null, [i]);
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
console.log(findGreaterNumbers([1, 2, 3]);        // 2: I want 3
console.log(findGreaterNumbers([6, 1, 2, 7]));    // 3: I want 4
console.log(findGreaterNumbers([5, 4, 3, 2, 1])); // 4: I want 0
console.log(findGreaterNumbers([]));              // undefined: I want 0
```

Comment: What's the point of calling `Math.max.apply()` with an array of just one element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
const findMax = (arr) => {
    const max = Math.max.apply(Math, arr);
    return arr.indexOf(max);
}
```

First you create a function that receives an array `arr` then inside this function you find the array element with the highest value by using the JS built in [Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) method. If you return this value will show you the maximum value of the numbers in the array you've supplied.

In order to return the index you can use the [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) array method to find its index. You return this value and you have the index of the maximum number in an array.

Comment: Why You had passes Math argument in math.max method i think there should be a null

Answer (score 0):

```js
const input = [1,5,3,4,0,-1];
function getMaxIndex() {
  const max = Math.max(...input);
  return input.findIndex((item) => item === max);
}

console.log(getMaxIndex())
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way!

```
function findGreaterNumbers(arr) {
    let count = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[i] < arr[j]) {
                count ++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}

findGreaterNumbers([1,2,3]) // 3
findGreaterNumbers([6,1,2,7]) // 4
findGreaterNumbers([5,4,3,2,1]) // 0
findGreaterNumbers([]) // 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and go for something simpler like:

```js
function findGreaterNumbers(array) {

  let max = array[0]; // initialize the maximum to the first element
  array.forEach((value) => { // fancier for loop that iterates through the 
                             // array, **value** is the placeholder for the 
                             // members
    if (value > max) {
      max = value;
    }

  }); //after the forEach, max will have the largest value

  return array.indexOf(max); // returns the index of max
}
```

Some more explanations: [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Thanks man I got your approach in a  second bcoz i am just the beginner in this development world  i don't know all that method and function stuff

Comment: My bad, let me add some comments to make it easier for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can find max number by `Math.max` and find index of max from `Array.indexOf`

```js
var numbers = [ 0, 1, 3, 2, 5, 10 , 4 ,6];

var max = Math.max(...numbers)

var index = numbers.indexOf(max)

console.log('Index of max', index)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the built-in [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) methods for arrays which are extremely useful. `map` transforms an array into another array of the same length, whereas `reduce` can be used to do any aggregation on the array itself. And finding lowest/highest values is just a special type of aggregation.

That said, the following method will give you all indices that correspond to the largest value:

```js
function iMax(array) {
    return array.reduce((m, d, i) => {
        return (m.length === 0 || d > m[0].d)
            ? [{d: d, i: i}]
            : (d === m[0].d ? m.concat({d: d, i: i}) : m)
    }, [])
        .map(d => d.i);
}

// Run tests
console.log(JSON.stringify([1, 2, 3]) + " => " + JSON.stringify(iMax([1, 2, 3])));
console.log(JSON.stringify([6, 1, 2, 7]) + " => " + JSON.stringify(iMax([6, 1, 2, 7])));
console.log(JSON.stringify([5, 4, 3, 2, 1]) + " => " + JSON.stringify(iMax([5, 4, 3, 2, 1])));
console.log(JSON.stringify([5, 4, 3, 5, 2, 1]) + " => " + JSON.stringify(iMax([5, 4, 3, 5, 2, 1])));
console.log(JSON.stringify([]) + " => " + JSON.stringify(iMax([])));
```

I also added an example with multiple max values. Note that indices in Javascript start with 0, if you need the indices you mentioned in your example, you can add 1 to the results (but I would not recommend it). Finally, if you need any other value than an empty array if there is no max value in the input array, you can have an `if` before returning the result.

Comment: Thank you so much it takes time to get into my head but i'll definitely take this approach in future  i had started learning programming in  for only 2 weeks i don't understand advance topics but again thanks for providing me good solving stuff